Getting different font size when run on different device ; need advice to pinpoint reason
per subject, for example, when i run my pdfplumber code on my main device, the height/size will be 10+ but on another device it will be 9. (same PDF file)
any advice on what settings may have affected this is greatly appreciated...
sample code (without actual PDF file)
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd

filePath = f""
oPDF = pdfplumber.open(filePath)
dfPDF = pd.DataFrame(oPDF.pages[0].chars)
dfPDF[["height","size"]]


Check that both devices are using the same versions of pdfplumber and pandas. Also, ensure system settings like DPI, fonts, and operating systems are consistent, as these can affect how the PDF is rendered and how sizes are interpreted.
